# How can I upload and image to Trello a trello, but NOT set it as Cover (which is the default setting)

Tags: python, api, trello

I'm uploading images to a Trello Card using the Trello API. Trello by default set the image as the cover image. The API documentation says there is a setCover option but I cannot get it work.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-attachments-post

```
def __upload_image_to_card(self, connection: dict, card: dict, image_path : str, cover=False):
    params = (
        ('key', connection['trello_api_key']),
        ('token', connection['trello_api_token']),
    )
    
    values = {
        'file': (image_path, open(image_path, 'rb')),
        'setCover' : (cover),
    }

    # TODO: Move to node_manager
    response = requests.post('https://api.trello.com/1/cards/%s/attachments' % card['id'], params=params, files=values).json()
```

I've tried switching between a boolean and string, have tried removing the brackets. I've even added a error key in values to see if I can get a different response. None stopped the image from being uploaded and none prevented the image from becoming the default image.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setCover` should be in `params`, not in `files`/`values`. You may also need to make it `str(cover).lower()` since it's expecting `true/false` and not `True/False`.

```py
# since you using a list of tuples:
params = (
    ('key', connection['trello_api_key']),
    ('token', connection['trello_api_token']),
    ('setCover', cover),
)
```

Or as a dict:

```py
params = {
    'key': connection['trello_api_key'],
    'token': connection['trello_api_token'],
    'setCover': cover,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I've converted my tuple to a dictionary as well.